# Jquery AJAX json - ошибки при вызове

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

При вызове веб-сервиса SAP (wsdl) возникает ошибка, пробую другими клиентами, все отлично работает, данный способ подключения использую впервые, куда и где копать подскажите?

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
     url: webserUrl,
     type: "GET",
     data: JSON.stringify({ "Tabn": "1","Vaccurrent": "1","Vacnext": "1" }),

     cache: false,
     crossDomain: true,
     username: "user", 
     password: "password",
     processData: false,
     contentType: "application/json",
     dataType: "json",
     headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
     xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
                },
     crossDomain: true,
      success: OnSuccess, 
      error: OnError
        });

        function OnSuccess(data, status)
    {
        alert(data);
    }
    function OnError(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError, request, error)
    {
        alert('xrs.status = ' + xhr.status + '\n' + 
            'thrown error = ' + thrownError + '\n' +
            'xhr.statusText = '  + xhr.statusText + '\n' +
            'request = ' + request + '\n' +
            'error = ' + error);
            console.log('xrs.status = ' + xhr.status + '\n' + 
            'thrown error = ' + thrownError + '\n' +
            'xhr.statusText = '  + xhr.statusText + '\n' +
            'request = ' + request + '\n' +
            'error = ' + error);
    }
 });
```

Ошибки:

```
xrs.status = 200 
thrown error = undefined 
xhr.statusText = OK 
request = undefined 
error = undefined
```

Comment: Приведите пример кода который можно было бы запустить.

Comment: Это точно неправильно data: JSON.stringify({ "Tabn": "1","Vaccurrent": "1","Vacnext": "1" }) если вы SOAP пытаетесь вызвать...

Comment: Пробовал и так, тоже не работает:  var soapRequest = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">'
           + '<soapenv:Header/>'
           + '<soapenv:Body>'
           + ' <urn:ZHrFWebservicesVac>'
           + '<Tabn>' + val1 + '</Tabn>'
           + '<Vaccurrent>' + val2 + '</Vaccurrent>'
           + '<Vacnext>' + val3 + '</Vacnext>'
           + ' </urn:ZHrFWebservicesVac>'             
           + '</soapenv:Body>'
        + '</soapenv:Envelope>';

Comment: Вы ведь понимаете, что в теле xml лежать должен?... вам надо библиотечку искать для js которая xml для SOAP генерить будет по WSDL

Comment: а можно пример привести?

Comment: type: "GET" а это? (надо POST)... Отлавливайте fiddler'ом запросы с SOAP UI и смотрите что он шлёт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо за ответы, поменял url с `wsdl` на `endpoint`, также изменил `content-type` на:

```
text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"
```

и все заработало.